# flutter nested ListViewSeparator

Tags: flutter

i have nested ListViewSeparator and i only have one problem as shown in the picture which is the expanded green color...i declared a height and width of the container by 30 but still it makes the green color expanded

[image]

this is my code:

```
Expanded(
                child: ListView.separated(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    itemBuilder: (context,index) => PlanDetails(context,index),
                    separatorBuilder: (context,index) => SizedBox(height: 10,),
                    itemCount: week!
                ),
              )
```

```
Widget PlanDetails(context,index) => Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
    child: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Text('Week ${index+1} | 0 Days'),
          SizedBox(height: 20,),
          ListView.separated(
            shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (context,index) => DaysDetails(context,index),
              separatorBuilder: (context,index) => SizedBox(width: 10,),
              itemCount: 3
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );

  Widget DaysDetails(context,index) => SizedBox(
    height: 30,width: 30,
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: Text('Day 1'),
    ),
  );
```

how to solve that    ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to handle it, You can wrap the `DaysDetails` widget with Align widget.

```dart
itemBuilder: (context, index) => Align(
      child: DaysDetails(context, index),
    ),
```

More about [layout/constraints](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/constraints)